# String to list without using regex

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a string as in

```
mystring = "1212, 1215, 2132, 2312, 3333"
```

What is the recommended approach to convert it into a list? as in

```
mylist = [1212, 1215, 2132, 2312, 3333]
```

Please note that mystring can assume a single value too, as in mystring = "1212"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
map(int, mystring.split(','))
```

That's it.

Comment: Ouch, it almost works. But it doesnt work when the string is only one element such as mystring=1212

Answer (score 6):

List comprehension syntax:

```
[int(n) for n in mystring.split(',')]
```